# Why Shri Krishna was happy when Ghatotkach died?

Tags: vishnu

I heard that Lord Krishna was happy when Ghatotkach was killed by Karna during mahabharata war Why was he happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The war of mahabharat was very deplomatic. Someone hadn't followed rules and cheats. In the war of mahabharat lord shri krishna had played very important role in the winning of pandvas. In mahabharat war the power was not in balance because in kaurav’s army was much powerful than pandav. In kaurav army bhishm pitamah, acharya dron, krapacharya, karna, ashvatthama and many others are very powerful. While in pandav’s army mostly pandav but shri krishna couldn't take weapon in war but they could use mind that's why pandav won.

Ghatotkashya was the son of pandav bhim and raksshi hidimba. So he had both raksshi power and humans power. He could change size also.

So we come on main point why shri krishna celebrate ghatotkashya death. When the Kaurava leader Duryodhana appealed to Karna, to kill Ghatotkacha as the whole Kaurava army was coming close to annihilation due to Ghatotkacha's attacks. Karna possessed a divine weapon called the Vasavi Shakti, granted by the god Indra. Only able to use it once, Karna had been saving it for his battle with his rival, Arjuna. Unable to refuse Duryodhana, Karna discharged the weapon against Ghatotkacha, killing him. It is said that when Ghatotkacha realized that he was going to die, that he assumed a gigantic size. When the huge body fell, it crushed one akshauhini of the Kaurava army. After his death Krishna was glad Karna no longer had Vasavi Sakthi to use against Arjuna.

Comment: But why was Shri Krishna happy isn't Ghatotkach was son of His cousin brother?

Comment: @SamratVikramSingh Ghatotkach was a demon. Lord Krishna knew that If Ghototkach would be alive then he will cause unrest in the world that's why he was happy.

Comment: @user30462 is Ghatotkacha adharmic?